# Reporting: Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When a pipeline has run we are able to view a report clicking on "tests and coverage". By default the report only lists Aborted and Failed.

Is there any way to set the default so that the report shows passes?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops#tests-tab)

> Results: lists all tests executed and reported as part of the current build or release. The default view shows only the failed and aborted tests in order to focus on tests that require attention. However, you can choose other outcomes using the filters provided.

It doesn't say that it cannot be changed but also doesn't mention that it is possible. Thus I assume you can't do that now. What you can do is to create a feature request on [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to add this functionality.